# WebMethod not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

Issues:

When showCurrentTime() is fired, the WebMethod GetCurrentTime() is never called.

The success function is firing and displaying an empty alert.

---

There is a script manager on the page.

JQuery is embedded.

Tried 
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("WebMethodTest2.aspx/GetCurrentTime") %>'. and get the same issues.

Tried enabling PageMethods then calling the WebMethod as follows and get the same issues.

```
        PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(onSuccess, onError);
        function onSuccess(resp) { alert(resp.d); }
        function onError(resp) { alert(resp.d); }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
       function showCurrentTime() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebMethodTest2.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) { alert(response.d); },
                failure: function (response) { alert(response.d); }
            });

        }
```

---

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this without realizing Asp.NET.FriendlyURLs are related to the issue.

In RouteConfig.cs comment out

```
  //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

Found the answer here:
[Authentication failed during call webmethod from jquery.ajx with AspNet.FriendlyUrls and AspNet.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032240/authentication-failed-during-call-webmethod-from-jquery-ajx-with-aspnet-friendly)