# Ajax not call the webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

The Ajax method not calling the webmethod. When I check in the browser it shows error data = Object {Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null,ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"} How to solve and also I try to change in the Route.config settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent; to settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; but it not solve.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".editButton", function () {
                    $("#myModal").focus();
                    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                    debugger;
                    console.log(id);
                    $("#btnUpdate").attr("edit-id", id);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("CustTableView.aspx/EditData") %>',
                        data:JSON.stringify({ eid: "" + id + "" }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {

                            var empDetails = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                            $.each(empDetails, function (index, value) {
                                debugger;
                                $("#CustomerCode").val(value.Code);
                                $("#CustomerName").val(value.Name);
                                $("#MailingName").val(value.MName);
                                $("#RegOfficeAddress").val(value.Address1);
                                $("#RegOfficeAddress1").val(value.Address2);
                                $("#RegOfficeAddress2").val(value.Address3);
                                $("#City").val(value.City);
                                $("#StateDropdown").val(value.State);
                                $("#CountryDropdown").val(value.Country);
                                $("#Address2-1").val(value.M2Address1);
                                $("#Address2-2").val(value.M2Address2);
                                $("#Address2-3").val(value.M2Address3);
                                $("#City2").val(value.M2City);
                                $("#StateAddress2").val(value.M2State);
                                $("#CountryAddress2").val(value.M2Country);
                                $("#Address3-1").val(value.M3Address1);
                                $("#Address3-2").val(value.M3Address2);
                                $("#Address3-3").val(value.M3Address3);
                                $("#City3").val(value.M3City);
                                $("#StateAddress3").val(value.M3State);
                                $("#CountryAddress3").val(value.M3Country);
                                $("#EmailAcc").val(value.Email);
                                $("#EmailDSR").val(value.Email1);
                                $("#ContPer").val(value.Contact);
                                $("#Telephone").val(value.TelNo1);
                                $("#FaxNo").val(value.TelNo2);
                                $("#MobileNo").val(value.TelNo3);
                                $("#StdCode").val(value.STDCode);
                                $("#ISDCODE").val(value.ISDCode);
                                $("#PanNO").val(value.PANNo);
                                $("#STNO").val(value.STNo);
                                $("#CSTTIN").val(value.CSTNo);
                                $("#VATTIN").val(value.VATNO);
                                $("#CINNO").val(value.TINNo);
                                $("#LedName").val(value.TallyLedger);
                                $("#TallyGroup").val(value.TallyGroup);
                                $("#CustomClearanceCheck").val(value.Contract1);
                                $("#PhotographCheck").val(value.Photo);
                                $("#PalletisationCheck").val(value.Pallet);
                                $("#FumigationCheck").val(value.Fumigation);
                                $("#LashingCheck").val(value.Lashing);
                                $("#WarehousingCheck").val(value.WareHouse);
                                $("#OriginCheck").val(value.Certificate);
                                $("#SurveyCheck").val(value.Survey);
                                $("#InsuranceCheck").val(value.Insurance);
                                $("#TramsportationCheck").val(value.Transport);
                                $("#ADCCheck").val(value.ADC);
                                $("#LandingCheck").val(value.IsLC);
                                $("#SICUTOFF").val(value.SICUTOFF);
                                $("#ActiveExport").val(value.DSRMail);
                                $("#ActiveImport").val(value.DSRMail1);
                                //$("#EstimateCost").val(value.);
                                $("#ActiveExporyAgent").val(value.AgentMail1);
                                $("#ActiveImportAgent").val(value.AgentMail2);


                                debugger;
                                getDetails();
                                //alert("hi");
                            });

                        },
                        error: function () {
                            debugger;
                            alert("Error while retrieving data of :" + id);
                        }
                    });

                })

    [WebMethod]
        public static string EditData(string eid)
        {
            string jsondata;
            using(var scon=new SqlConnection(strConnection))
            {
                var query = "select Code,Name,MName,Address1,Address2,Address3,City,State,Country,M2Address1,M2Address2,M2Address3,M2City,M2State,M2Country,M3Address1,M3Address2,M3Address3,M3City,M3State,M3Country,TelNo1,TelNo2,TelNo3,Email,Email1,Contact,STDCode,ISDCode,PANNo,STNo,CSTNo,VATNO,TINNo,TallyLedger,TallyGroup,Contract1,Photo,Pallet,Fumigation,Lashing,WareHouse,Certificate,Survey,Insurance,Transport,ADC,IsLC,SICUTOFF,DSRMail,DSRMail1,AgentMail1,AgentMail2 from PartyLedger where Code='" + eid +"' ";
                using(var cmd=new SqlCommand(query,scon))
                {

                    using(var sda=new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = scon;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        TableData.Clear();
                        sda.Fill(TableData);
                        jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TableData).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            return jsondata.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: It is the problem on the page `CustTableView.aspx/EditData`. Looks like your page is secure.   Try making the page unsecure.

Comment: no page is not secure..

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032240/authentication-failed-during-call-webmethod-from-jquery-ajx-with-aspnet-friendly