# Webmethod jquery ajax call not returning any results

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Hi I am building a web media gallery for which,

I've a simple webmethod to fetch tags from database.

```
public class Tags
        {
            public string tag_ID { get; set; }
            public string tag { get; set; }
            public string total_count { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static List<Tags> GetTags()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["taggerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "GetTagCount";
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    List<Tags> tag = new List<Tags>();
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            tag.Add(new Tags
                            {
                                tag_ID = sdr["tag_ID"].ToString(),
                                tag = sdr["tag"].ToString(),
                                total_count = sdr["total_count"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    return tag;
                }
            }
        }
```

and a javascript which I call on button click to display the result in a div.
But I am not getting any result in the call. No errors are also being displayed.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { $('#getTags').click(myFunction); });

        function myFunction() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/App/WebForm1.aspx/GetTags",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });

            function OnSuccess(response) {
                var Tags = response.d;
                $(Tags).each(function () {
                    var tag = this.tag;
                    $("#results").append(" <b>" + tag + "</b>. ");
                })
            };
        }
```

Comment: Hi guys, I've separately tested all three suggestions given. No positive results yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a line after cmd.CommandText = "GetTagCount"; it is cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: You were right. But that wasn't the root cause. My service was not being called at all. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting this in Web.Config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
          <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

You webservice code will be:

```
public class Tags
{
    public string tag_ID { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string total_count { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static void GetTags()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["taggerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "GetTagCount";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            List<Tags> tag = new List<Tags>();
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    tag.Add(new Tags
                    {
                        tag_ID = sdr["tag_ID"].ToString(),
                        tag = sdr["tag"].ToString(),
                        total_count = sdr["total_count"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            conn.Close();

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            string result = jSearializer.Serialize(tag);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(result);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No result. No change.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the solution.

When I tried to troubleshoot using chrome's network tab..I got this result.

```
{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

From which I understood that its because of configuration in template

in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs this line:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

In one of the post on SO ([Authentication failed during call webmethod from jquery.ajx with AspNet.FriendlyUrls and AspNet.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032240/authentication-failed-during-call-webmethod-from-jquery-ajx-with-aspnet-friendly))

it was suggested to comment it.

Now since this is done. Can any one suggest pros & cons of commenting out this line. If its not a good idea from security point of view, any workaround.?