# Calling a WebMethod from the click event of dynamically added Button control in Asp.net does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethods

I am unable to call the web method from the `click` event of the dynamically added `Button` control.
Here is the C# Code

```
public partial class Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "Click Me.";
            button.OnClientClick = "return Remove()";
            pnlFiles.Controls.Add(button);
  
       
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void ClickEvent(int id)
    {
        
        

    }
}
```

Here is the javascript

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Remove() {
             
            $.ajax({
                url:"Default.aspx/ClickEvent",
                data: "{'id':5}",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {

                    alert(msg);

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         
                }
            });
         
        }
    </script>
```

Here is the HTML

```html
  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlFiles" />
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: jQuery $.ajax error response  text is 
"Authentication Failed"

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public void static ClickEvent(int i)
{
    
   
}
```

I think WebMethod should be static. Also Use JSON.stringify for data. This should solve the problem. If not, you can try and see if there is any error in network tab of chrome dev console.

Note: keep the param name of c# method same as the param you are passing in json body.

Comment: I incorporated all your suggestions, but it still does not work. There is no error in the network tab either.

Comment: What is coming in network tab, is call being made in to server? or is the network tab empty? if call is being made, what is the uri, body, method etc.
edit: also can you add a debugger in remove() function and check if function is being triggered?

Comment: Yes, Remove() method triggered. And now I can see that the response text is "Authentication Failed".

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20052866/7819056

Answer (score 0):

jQuery $.ajax error response text was "Authentication Failed". I commented out the following line in RouteConfig.cs and it worked.

```
  jQuery $.ajax error response text is "Authentication Failed"
```